# How to fix the problem that a gravity form plugin is hit on the google test speed mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, google-pagespeed

How to fix the problem that a gravity form plugin is hit on the google test speed mobile devices?
The scores with gravity form show 32%.
The scores without gravity form show 78%.
because the plugin gravity form put the script code inline on the page html code....that why the score falling on the speed test.

Comment: What plugin are you using, so we can check different methods

Comment: gravity form plugin

Comment: If you know what needs to be changed (put the script in a document ready handler?), you can always do it yourself. You have the plugin as source code after all. Else you'll probably have to talk to Gravity Forms support to ask if they'll fix it. That is assuming it is actually a problem in practice beyond just this statistic.